# Using remote access or root user to hack the MAC?

Tags: security, wireless-access-point

I just bumped into [this story](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4989968?start=0&tstart=0) when I was looking for some info.It seems that other than visual aspects like allowing remote access via system access,intruders can also use Terminal to do a lot of evils if they are on the same LAN. Would someone please let me know how can I get sure that I have not same problem?How can I get sure when I am connecting WLAN of workplace nobody can hack my computer and if they did by any chance(having password) how can I hinder the problem?How a MAC could have two syslog? And if there is problem how can I get rid of it?I am scared I might leave my Mac unattended sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

"As long as your roommate has physical access to the Mac & knows what he is doing, there is no way to prevent him from hacking it"

Quite simply, every single common modern OS has ways for you to get into it - from [konboot](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/03/01/kon-boot-getting-into-a-clients-computer-without-using-a-portal-gun/) to changing the password, to single user mode. There's nearly no way to secure a system with physical access. You can reduce the risk by setting up a password to allow booting, and encrypting your filesystem with filevault. This will make a casual intrusion harder.

As for online access - disable anything you don't need, and [set up key based authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-setup-sshd-on-mac-os-x-to-only-allow-key-based-authentication). If you need remote access to the system use *only* an ssh tunnel. Disallow root remote logins and [allow only specific users to log in](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10618). I'd also suggest using an uncommon port for a little more obscurity.